# Honeycomb gallery sample

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

There is a [link](http://developer.android.com/shareables/HoneycombGalleryV2.zip) on the android dev [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) to application example which works on both handsets and tablets, but there is `android:minSdkVersion="11"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` which assumes tablets rather than handsets. When I decreased the min version the application just didn't start. What did I miss?

Comment: Without seeing that particular sample app: That post relates to Ice Cream Sandwich, that's the next (currently not published) version of android that will run on phones. It will have a higher API level than 11. The app probably uses features that were introduced on api lvl 11. ICS will support these, current phone versions don't.

Comment: Oh yeah! Please answer below so I can close the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing that particular sample app: That post relates to Ice Cream Sandwich, that's the next (currently not published) version of android that will run on phones. It will have a higher API level than 11. The app probably uses features that were introduced on api lvl 11. ICS will support these, current phone versions don't.

Comment: To follow up (I wrote much of that sample) - That application does use several features introduced in Honeycomb-  Specifically it makes heavy use of fragments and the Action Bar.  As a result it won't run in anything pre-Honeycomb :)